# How to get counts for unique column values across multiple columns/rows in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table

The question can be better framed so feel free to edit it but I am providing an example below to exactly describe what I need help in.

I have a pandas DataFrame. Ideally I would have typed in the column values (excuse me for that).
[image]

The output I am looking for this end result. I have tried using `pd.groupby` and `pd.pivot_table` but have not been able to write something for which I do not have to iterate through all the rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot and then [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('Products')
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['Products'], df1['value'])
```